# linux zip command not contains parent folder

Tags: linux, zip, unzip

I have a question about zip cmd in linux ,when I want to zip a folder and its sub files,but I won't zip it contains the folder name ,I use the cmd as that:   `zip -r foldername.war foldername/`.
but when I unzip the `foldername.war` to folder like this:
`zip foldername.war -d foldername` .
The dir will be `foldername/foldername/files`.I don't want this ,I just want 
foldername/files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how you are using zip and unzip command, but you can follow below steps for directories :-

To zip a dir issue following command :-

`zip -r foldername.war foldername/`

To unzip a zip file, issue following command :-

`unzip foldername.war`

you will have following structure :-

`tree foldername`

```
foldername
|-- a
|-- b
`-- c
```

Comment: Thanks,I fell into an infinite loop and formed a mind-set,it really resolve my confusion